# SUM timestampdiff of multiple durations per day

Tags: mysql

I'm having a table from my thermostat.
It records data as follows.
So when it switches on, I get a timestate with Status 1 meaning on, Status 0 mean heating switches off. Additionally it gives me with every on/off the total heatings per day.

```
Date                | Status | Total_heatings
2019-01-20 10:00:00 | 1      | 1
2019-01-20 10:10:00 | 0      | 1
2019-01-20 14:00:00 | 1      | 2
2019-01-20 14:25:00 | 0      | 2
2019-01-20 18:00:00 | 1      | 3
2019-01-20 18:15:00 | 0      | 3
2019-01-21 01:00:00 | 1      | 1
2019-01-21 01:30:00 | 0      | 1
2019-01-21 06:00:00 | 1      | 2
2019-01-21 06:15:00 | 0      | 2
```

I'm trying to get the total duration by day. I tried the below script, which gives me the durations for the multiple heating sessions for each day.
When I use `SUM(TIMESTAMPDIFF(Minute,Min(Date),MAX(Date)))` it throws an error because of wrong usage of grouping.

```
SELECT 
   DATE_FORMAT(Date, '%d.%m') AS 'day',
   TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE,MIN(Date),MAX(Date)) AS 'Duration'
FROM thermostat 
   WHERE (Date BETWEEN '2019-01-21 00:00:00' + INTERVAL -7 DAY AND '2019-01-21 00:00:00') 
   GROUP BY DAY(Date),Total_heatings;
```

All I would need is to get a SUM by day of these various heating sessions per day.
So the result should have the following:

```
Day   | Duration
20.01 | 50
21.01 | 45
```

Now I'm stuck with not being able to further summing all heating session per day, like total duration each day.
Thanks a lot for any pointers and help.

Comment: question, if you order by date column, will the status 0 be always followed by a 1 and a 1 by 0?

Comment: What happens when it turns on at 23:55 and turns off at 01:20?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This query will work for MySQL versions before 8.0. It uses a `SELF JOIN` to find matching `heater off` rows for a given `heater on` row. Where a matching row doesn't exist, it uses either the end of the day or the current time, whichever is lower.

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(t1.Date, '%d.%m') AS `day`,
       SUM(TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE, t1.Date, COALESCE(t2.Date, LEAST(NOW(), DATE(t1.Date) + INTERVAL 1 DAY)))) AS Duration,
       MAX(t1.Total_heatings) AS Total_heatings
FROM thermostat t1
LEFT JOIN thermostat t2 ON t2.Status = 0 AND t2.Total_heatings = t1.Total_heatings AND DATE(t2.Date) = DATE(t1.Date)
WHERE t1.Status = 1 AND DATE(t1.Date) BETWEEN '2019-01-21' - INTERVAL 7 DAY AND '2019-01-21' 
GROUP BY `day`
```

Output:

```
day     Duration    Total_heatings
20.01   50          3
21.01   45          2
```

[Demo on dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=9c7cb7050d739e46247adebc6f09a875)

Comment: wonderful, that works like a charm. thanks a lot.
As I only have MySQL 5.6 your script is the only one I can use.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using MySQL 8, you can use window function `LAG` to access the previous switch. In the outer query, you can filter on intervals where the previous status was on.

```
SELECT
    DATE_FORMAT(x.date, '%d.%m'),
    SUM(TIMESTAMPDIFF( minute, x.date, x.last_date) duration
FROM (
    SELECT 
        t.*,
        LAG(t.date) OVER (PARTITION BY DATE_FORMAT(t.date, '%d.%m') ORDER BY t.date) last_date,
        LAG(t.status) OVER (PARTITION BY DATE_FORMAT(t.date, '%d.%m') ORDER BY t.date) last_status
    FROM mytable t
) x
WHERE x.last_status = 1
GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(x.date, '%d.%m')
ORDER BY 1
```

In [this db fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/wBweu7aKnAhG7f3AHY8XQz/5), this matches your expected output.

Answer (score 0):

[Using window function](http://www.artfulsoftware.com/infotree/queries.php#1835) available in MySQL-8.0 and MariaDB-10.2:

```
select DATE(ts) as 'day', sum(ontime) as 'on time'
from (
  select status, lead(ts,1,ts) over w - ts as 'ontime'
  from (
    select unix_timestamp(ts) as ts, status
    from t
    order by ts
  ) x
  window w as (order by ts)
) y
where status=1
group by 'day';
```